# API Gateway cache per tenant in SAAS Multi-tenant Environment

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am building a multi-tenant SAAS application, which has an API gateway at: `https://foobar.com/api/resources?hello=world` which I would like to add caching to. I am using the `Cognito` Authorizer. All tenants currently hit the same URL, that is, there is no `tenantId` in the URL. Based on Claims in the Identity Token, a client hitting the API will receive different resources. When a user hits my endpoint they will have a claim in their identity token :`{ 'custom:tenantId' : '123'}`, so I know what resources belong to that tenant.

This endpoint will receive many requests. And I would like to do caching, per-tenant. What I mean by that is if I only do caching based on the URL params: 
[image: Caching]
Then a client on `tenantA` could see `tenantB` resources because the cache is dumb and doesn't take `custom:tenantId` into account. I could cache per client pretty easily by adding the `Authorization` header to caching, but that would be very inefficient. I've tried being fancy in the Integration Request, by doing:

[image: Integration Request]
But it doesn't seem that expression works

**Work Around:**

I now realize this kind of breaks the URL pattern, in that the same URL is returning a different `resource(s)`. I have considered whether or not this is a design flaw, and if I should add `tenantId` into the subdomain or into the URL:

```
`https://{tenantId}.foobar.com/api/resources?hello=world`
```

OR

```
`https://foobar.com/{tenantId}/api/resources?hello=world`
```

**Question**
Are there any ways to achieve caching per tenant, without having to change the URL?

Comment: I have the exact same question, how can we avoid someone to change the "tenantID" and see the contents of others tenants??? Maybe creating a custom authorizer prepending información in the autorizacion header? Maybe simply using a perKeyInvalidation based on headers?

Comment: I sked this a while ago I should write an answer to this but TBH don't have enough time atm. But basically you are right, you will need a custom authorizer, which can populate `authorizer.context.tenantId`, and use that as a cache key somewhere as in your http proxy request. If you can't do that then you need to include the `tenantId` in the URL or Header, and have a custom authorizer check that the tenantId a user is requesting is that same as where they belong to. IMO the best way is to include the tenantId in the URL, and write a custom authorizer to enforce a user accesses the correct one.

Comment: Thanks @Snickers3192, I could make the job using a Custom Header but if you tell me authorizer context variables can be used as cache key so i'll prefer an authorizer context variable in my others futurs developments, much more safe!

Comment: Have you found a way to invalidate the API Gateway cache from backend (lambda?). In my case, I am using `new AWS.APIGateway()` and `flushStageCache` function but it's invalidate all the cache and is not very good.

Comment: No the API gateway cache cannot be used like a Redis cache, you would need to use an elasticache service or something else if you wanted to do invalidation. If you didn't want to deploy another service, you could use another parameter as a cache key, and generate a guid or something unique so that you force a cache miss for that specific request, or provide another endpoint with no caching on it and use that when you want a fresh response. But you can't invalidate server side AFAIK for API gateway which is fine, it is common to have caching at multiple stages and is a valid pattern.